# Get current state of webcam in C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, directshow, aforge

I am trying to figure out how to check if a webcam/video capture device is already being used by another application without actually activating it.

My current approach is to use the AForge.NET library and using the .IsRunning property of the VideoCaptureDevice object like this:

```
 var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                
 foreach (FilterInfo videoDevice in videoDevices)
 {
    VideoCaptureDevice camera new AForge.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevice.MonikerString);
    Debug.Print(camera.IsRunning)
 }
```

I guess the IsRunning property only works on VideoCaptureDevices that have been started using the library and I need lower-level DirectShow access to the device.

While there are many ways to use DirectShow in C#, I have been unable to find a way to check the state even using DirectShow in C++. Is there some magic I need to perform here?

Thanks

Tobias Timpe

Comment: I guess you could register for a [CameraCaptureStateChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.appbroadcaststate.cameracapturestatechanged) event.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'll check it out, thank you!

Comment: Is the method provided by IInspectable  useful to you?

Comment: Not really, it supports only UWP apps while mine should be running in the background with a NotifyIcon.

Comment: Have you verified this? The documentation is frequently outdated, and frequently doesn't name the `DualApiPartitionAttribute` for types, that *are* available to classic Desktop applications. Indeed, the number of UWP-only WinRT types is close to zero.

Comment: I think the only way is to attempt to start video capture. In most cases your application does not even talk to a webcam, and talks to proxy instead. I don't think notifications of your interest exist. There is no specific well defined way to check either, other than doing the capture.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not entirely sure if this will be helpful to you, but I found your question because I wanted to write a custom app to control my busylight. This is very much 'Works On My Machine' certified - it's not an attempt to give a general answer. However, I figure it may help you, and possibly the next person who comes across this page while googling...

```
private static bool IsWebCamInUse()
{
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\NonPackaged"))
    {
        foreach (var subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
            {
                if (subKey.GetValueNames().Contains("LastUsedTimeStop"))
                {
                    var endTime = subKey.GetValue("LastUsedTimeStop") is long ? (long) subKey.GetValue("LastUsedTimeStop") : -1;
                    if (endTime <= 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm setting up an Adafruit TrinketM0 as a custom busylight and I wanted to check if the webcam is active, then set it to busy. I did have to set the target platform to 64bit because the keys were null. `Properties > Build > Platform Target = x64` I also had to use LocalMachine `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey...`.

Comment: I just updated Windows 10 from 1909 to 2004 and my process stopped working. After googling I came across this answer again and my own comment! When I saw what I had done before, I thought maybe if I change the registry key back to `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey...` it would work again? YES, IT DID! That's why it didn't work the first time I tried it. I was using an older build of Windows 10 than what @Matt Whitfield was using. Now all is well, and I got my homegrown busy light working again.

Comment: I did run into an issue where `key` is null when running the process as a service. I got around this by running the service as myself but that's just a workaround. I assume when running the service as LocalSystem, it doesn't have access to `CurrentUser` and that's why it's null.

Comment: @FarFigNewton - yeah CurrentUser isn't a thing when you're running as LocalSystem 