# Is there a sensible way to detect if a users is on a video call, in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a tool that helps me to track what I am doing with my time. I tell it what task I'm on, intermittently.

Because I'm bad at remembering to update the current task, I have it set up so that (whenever I'm using my computer) it prompts me "what are you doing?" every 15 minutes, so that I remember to update it. And if it realises I've been afk for 15 minutes then it records that the previous task stopped 15 minutes ago.

It uses mouse and keyboard hooks to detect that activity.

So far, so good.

But alas, I'm now spending lots of time on video calls, during which I'm working, but not giving mouse or keyboard inputs. So the tool (reasonably) decides that I must not be working. #sad

Is there any not-horribly-hacky way to detect "user is in a video call?"

If it's relevant my video tools are mainly Teams & Slack; sometimes Skype.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this approach sounds interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/hcq5qj/detecting_if_miccamera_is_in_use/

Comment: - [How to check if a microphone is available for recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477590/how-to-check-if-a-microphone-is-available-for-recording)
- [Detect if webcam is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650097/get-current-state-of-webcam-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The available time tracking tools write into their logs the current active window title, whenever the window changes. So you get an overview, what you did and you can later more easily decide what the corresponding project should be.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Powertoys has an implementation that detects if you are in a Video Conference. [Source Code](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/main/src/modules/videoconference/VideoConferenceModule) [Powertoys Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/video-conference-mute)